# Java array extension/reduction

Tags: java, algorithm, array

I work with the Oracle JGeometry method which returns (or takes as method argument) 2D segments as double array (x1,y1,x2,y2 ... xn,yn). I need to extend this array to contain 3D segments as double array (x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2 ... xn,yn,zn) by default Z value or reduce to 2D (by removing of all Z coordinate). I wrote simple utility methods for making this. Is there any easier or smarter way to do this?

The conversion from 2D to 3D:

```
public static double[] to3D(double z, double[] inputArray) {
    List<Double> convertedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        convertedItems.add(inputArray[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
            convertedItems.add(z);
        }
    }
    return convertedItems.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
}
```

The conversion from 3D to 2D:

```
public static double[] to2D(double[] inputArray) {
    List<Double> convertedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
       if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
           continue;
       }
       convertedItems.add(inputArray[i]);     
    }
    return convertedItems.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with primitive Arrays, instead of using Collections and Streams in this case.

```
public static double[] to3D(double z, double[] in) {
    // Pre-allocated array 1.5 size of the original array
    double[] out = new double[in.length * 3 / 2];
    //loop with a step 2
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < in.length; i += 2) {
        out[j++] = in[i];
        out[j++] = in[i + 1];
        out[j++] = z;
    }
    return out;
}

public static double[] to2D(double[] in) {
    // Pre-allocated array 2/3 size of the original array
    double[] out = new double[in.length * 2 / 3];
    //loop with a step 3
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < in.length; i += 3) {
        out[j++] = in[i];
        out[j++] = in[i + 1];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Reasons for using arrays instead of lists: Input and output both are arrays, the target size is known, we only need basic operations and they would be faster in this case.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Just a small remark: Starting with `j = -1` seems a bit ugly. Using post increment (`j++`)  and starting with `j = 0` seems "nicer".

Comment: You are right, I just do it to avoid last unused post-increment, If you think it still should have that then you can edit it or tell me if I must, Thanks

Comment: You can include `int j = 0` directly inside the loop and you could explain why you are using arrays instead of lists (fixed cardinality of arrays).

Comment: In this case `int j = 0` cannot be initialised inside loop because it needs incremented value  in each iteration.

Comment: I badly explained it, I meant `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < in.length; i += 3)`.

Comment: If you want send a message to  an user you have to use `@username` in your message , see [how-do-comment-replies-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: @dariosicily - sure, thanks, edited the answer.

Comment: You are welcome.